# What is this (seed/berry)-like object and where is it coming from?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees, fruit

I've been finding these little green (seed/berry) like objects in my garden for three years now.

[image: large variant]

This picture shows either a large variant or simply  a later lifecycle stage of development.

At their smallest, they look artificial - kind of like *nerds* candy - almost too green to be natural.  In the picture above, it is obvious that the item is a berry, but at the smallest sizes, my first thought was that it was fertilizer.  And indeed, I would've continued to think that if not for two things:

1. We re-mulched our garden two years ago, and didn't fertilize (nor have we ever, but this house is only 3 years old).
2. When you squeeze even the smallest sized objects, they squirt juice or water.

When the larger berries are crushed, many little seeds come out along with liquid; and it looks almost like a miniature pickled tomato.

There is nothing in my garden that produces any kind of visible berries; and I've never seen one of these attached to a plant.  That is part of what makes them so odd (and part of what made me think they were fertilizer); I always find them mixed (sometimes deeply) in soil or mulch.

If no one knows after a couple days, I'll go take a picture of one of the baby ones to help.  Any thoughts?

**Location:** Brighton, MI (USA).

**Update:**. Here are some other shots.  These are both flash shots because it is overcast today.  These are also of the *younger* variant because I couldn't find any  of the mature berries today.  Hope this helps.

[image: Size Comparison]

[image: Another]

Comment: Other photos that would help: close-up of where the 'stem' joins the 'fruit' (assuming that's what it is); sectioned (sliced in half with a razor) rather than squished, and maybe an 'in situ' shot of one where you found it in the surroundings of your garden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Barring further details or photos, your fruits remind me of the [drupe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupe)  from a hackberry ([*Celtis spp.*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celtis))  tree.

[image: http://woodyplants.wdfiles.com/local--files/celtis-occidentalis/Celtis_occidentalis_fruit.JPG]

Hackberry drupes are relatively small, often being only about 6-10mm in diameter.

Examples:
[1](http://www.123rf.com/photo_7493381_southern-hackberry-celtis-laevigata-leaves-and-fruit.html), 
[2](http://woodyplants.wdfiles.com/local--files/celtis-occidentalis/Celtis_occidentalis_fruit.JPG).

Do you have any warty looking trees nearby? 
(like [this](http://0.tqn.com/d/forestry/1/S/D/i/twig_bark_hackbark.jpg)).

Do you ever see the fruits in a different color? (purple, black, red, orange)?

Comment: I think you are right.  In response to your questions:  Different color: maybe purple - though I wouldn't necessarily realized they were the same with other colors.  We have a nearby golf course with warty trees, though it's quite a long stones throw away.  But my sense is that you are likely spot on